# System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'ID'

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

I've been having this error with ASP.NET. and it just seems to be on going. I fix one thing then it leads to another error. I had this previous problem which I asked on here: [Issue with inserts and updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870247/issue-with-inserts-and-updates). Now in the top answer, I was told to numerous things to help fix my code; however, after I inserted "DataKeyNames="ID"" as told I get this error... I have no idea why

Now note in the gridview, i have a `"DataKeyNames="ID"`, which is then linked to `<asp:BoundField DataField="ID" Visible="false" />` 
Here is the Stack Trace:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'ID'.]
   System.Web.UI.DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Object container, String propName) +9502089
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +3140
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +67
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +14
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +123
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +33
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +138
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +30
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +105
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +75
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974
```

My ASP.NET:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MedicalOffice.aspx.cs" Inherits="MedicalOffice" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>

        <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <h1>Maintain Patients<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdDoctorList" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MedicalOfficeConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="uspDoctorList" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdPatient" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MedicalOfficeConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="usp_PatientDelete" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" InsertCommand="uspPatientInsert" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="uspPatientSelectByIDOrSelectAll" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="uspPatientUpdate" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="OHIP" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="DOB" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="VisitsPerYear" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="DoctorID" Type="Int32" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" DefaultValue="0" Name="DoctorID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                </SelectParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="OHIP" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="DOB" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="VisitsPerYear" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="DoctorID" Type="Int32" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </h1>
            <p>Select Patient By Doctor:<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="sdDoctorList" DataTextField="Doctor" DataValueField="ID" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">All Doctors</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="sdPatient" GridLines="Horizontal" DataKeyNames="ID">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" Visible="false" />
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OHIP" SortExpression="OHIP">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OHIP") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OHIP") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DOB" SortExpression="DOB">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DOB") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DOB") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Visits Per Year" SortExpression="VisitsPerYear">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VisitsPerYear") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VisitsPerYear") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Doctor" SortExpression="Doctor">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdDoctorList" DataTextField="Doctor" DataValueField="ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("DoctorID") %>' >
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Doctor") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#339966" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#487575" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#275353" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Why are you using patientID when everywhere else you have ID?

Comment: Sorry, I tried something different and it didn't help. I still get the same error.

Comment: question has been fixed

Comment: You really need to narrow this down some. There's no way you'll get an answer as the question is. The problem is simple. The query you used did not return an "ID" column.

Comment: its funny you said that lol. Query was the key word that helped my solve my problem thanks haha. Didn't know it was sql related.