# Convert varchar to timestamp in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, timestamp

There is table with `timestamp` column in SQL Server 2008 R2. When I only add this column to my table I see values like this `0x00000000000007D1`. I try to put data into it:

```
UPDATE test_time SET date3=
CONVERT(TIMESTAMP, CONVERT(datetime,'2002-08-20 14:00:00.000',120))
WHERE ogr_fid=1
```

But get error

> Cannot update timestamp column

What's wrong here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592658/sql-server-updating-a-time-stamp-column

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Server's `TIMESTAMP` datatype has **nothing** to do with a date and time!

It's just a binary representation of a consecutive number - it's only good for making sure a row hasn't change since it's been read.

In never versions of SQL Server, it's being called `RowVersion` - since that's really what it is. See the [MSDN docs on ROWVERSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx):

> *Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary numbers within a database. rowversion is generally used as a mechanism
>   for version-stamping table rows. The
>   rowversion data type is **just an incrementing number and does not
>   preserve a date or a time**. To record a date or time, use a datetime2
>   data type.*

So you **cannot** convert a string to a `TIMESTAMP` in SQL Server.

Comment: In different software timestamp are not same thing?

Comment: @KliverMax: in other database systems, `timestamp` is indeed used for date and time. But for SQL Server - it's not.