# ExecuteNonQuery error

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I need to update my database to set a date to the current timestamp. However, my ExecuteNonQuery is giving an exception "Incorrect syntax near ')' ". Can anyone tell me what is wrong?
This is the function with the error:

```
protected void setprint(object sender, EventArgs ev)
{
    GridViewRow row = ((LinkButton)sender).Parent.Parent as GridViewRow;
    inv = row.Cells[1].ToString().Trim();

    con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
    cmd = new SqlCommand("update invdata set ViewDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() where InvoiceNumber= '" + inv + "'", con);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (con != null)
            con.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: You should use parameterised queries.  This query is open to a SQL injection attack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Comment: @Paddy while true, this does nothing to answer his question

Comment: @DavidPilkington - I know, you have already answered it.  This is why it is a comment (in an attempt to be helpful) rather than an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, use GetDate() function to get current date and time.

Answer (score 4):

[`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188751.aspx) should not have `()`

So change it to

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("update invdata set ViewDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where InvoiceNumber= '" + inv + "'", con);
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. But now it's saying 'cannot update a timestamp column'. Is this true?

Comment: @kray Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592658/sql-server-updating-a-time-stamp-column it is updated automatically

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend adding your SQL Connection into a using block this way the connection is disposed and you do not have to manually close it in a finally block.

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString())) ;
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("update invdata set ViewDate = GETDATE() where InvoiceNumber= '" + inv + "'", con);


            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

}