# Adding Timestamp column to the key and eliminating duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add `Timestamp` column to the key constraint that has several columns.

This column don't have millisecond part at the time stamp.
The problem that there may be same times at the `Timestamp` column.I try to eliminate them with adding some random millisecond part.

My query:

```
update [vM].[dbo].[Operator] 
set [vM].[dbo].[Operator].Timestamp = DATEADD(MS , A.RowNumber*3 % 1000 , A.Timestamp),
    OperatorID = A.OperatorID ,
    ActionID = A.ActionID ,
    McID = A.McID ,
    Station = A.Station ,
    Slot = A.Slot ,
    SubSlot = A.SubSlot,
    FeederID = A.FeederID,
    CompID = A.CompID,
    Description = A.Description
from
 (SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by timestamp)) % 1000  as RowNumber , *
  FROM [vM].[dbo].[Operator]
  WHERE DATEPART(ms,Timestamp) % 1000 = 0) as A
```

I am getting error `The duplicate key value is (Dec  7 2014 10:54AM, ??, 28, 23).`  this is the original record that I try to update.

Original time that I have is `2014-12-07 10:54:52.000`

What is wrong with my query ? Is there more officiant way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Do you updating `timestamp` colimn before? Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592658/sql-server-updating-a-time-stamp-column), may be that is the problem.

Comment: @ Bogdan Bogdanov, timestamp here is not the datatype of the column it's only it's name (someone once took that bad name)  the datatype is datetime. So this is no the issue.

Comment: Ok, I was mislead by the name, sorry. As I see from your query you will update only rows which ms are 0. I just guess that you try to update several rows with the same ms - for me this sound as a reason. I can not see your data, but I think you can check if there a duplicate rows (try to convert update to select to check) or the ms are duplicate. If I were you I wil try to prepare table with 1000 rows (use that as ms to add) and try to join it to the update and get random rows using `NEWID()`. In that case you will be sure that you update with different ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one if you have less than 1000 values with equal timestamp

```
update [vM].[dbo].[Operator] 
set [vM].[dbo].[Operator].Timestamp = DATEADD(MS , A.RowNumber , A.Timestamp),
    OperatorID = A.OperatorID ,
    ActionID = A.ActionID ,
    McID = A.McID ,
    Station = A.Station ,
    Slot = A.Slot ,
    SubSlot = A.SubSlot,
    FeederID = A.FeederID,
    CompID = A.CompID,
    Description = A.Description
from
 (SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by timestamp Order by timestamp)) as RowNumber , *
  FROM [vM].[dbo].[Operator]
  WHERE DATEPART(ms,Timestamp) % 1000 = 0) as A
```

May be trouble happens when you reach big RowNumber values

Comment: I am getting the same error with your query: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Operator__E4D5102C84623F5A'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Operator'. The duplicate key value is (Dec  7 2014 10:54AM, ??, 28, 23).

Comment: Did you check that you update less than 1000 rows, @Night Walker (as Viktor Bardakov suggested)?

Comment: @Bogdan Bogdanov I have only one entry there.