# How to design a SQL table where a field has many descriptions

Tags: sql

I would like to create a product table. This product has unique part numbers. However, each part number has various number of previous part numbers, and various number of machines where the part can be used.

For example the description for **part no:** AA1007

**Previous part no's:** AA1001, AA1002, AA1004, AA1005,...

**Machine brand:** Bosch, Indesit, Samsun, HotPoint, Sharp,...

**Machine Brand Models:** Bosch A1, Bosch A2, Bosch A3, Indesit A1, Indesit A2,....

I would like to create a table for this, but I am not sure how to proceed. What I have been able to think is to create a table for Previous Part no, Machine Brand, Machine Brand Models individually.

**Question:** what is the proper way to design these tables?

Comment: You might need a whole bunch of tables. You should read up on SQL relations. many to one and many to many

Comment: Mapping table...

Comment: PartSynonyms table perhaps? current part Number is in "parts" table wherea s PartSynonyms lists the main part ID along with individual records for each synonym for that part.

Comment: We really need to understand how this data is to be used, reported upon, if you need to be able to regenerate information based on dates etc.  Keeping a Active from and active to date may work if multiple parts could be active at the same time; and a column which indicates replaced by and shows the parent record replacing that part allowing you to traverse a hierachy to find the current part.  Just too many unknowns IMO to provide a good quality answr.

Comment: @xQbert I plan to extract 3 different reports (or gridviews). 1- Price View, 2-Historical Price View 3-Item specs. However, I did not include them in my question in order to avoid asking a broad question. I plan to keep track of them using both timestamp and datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are of course various ways to design the tables. A very basic way would be:

You could create tables like below. I added the columns `ValidFrom` and `ValidTill`, to identify at which time a part was active/in use.
It depends on your data, if datatype `date` is enough, or you need `datetime` to make it more exactly.

```
CREATE TABLE Parts
(
      ID            bigint NOT NULL
     ,PartNo        varchar(100)
     ,PartName      varchar(100)
     ,ValidFrom     date
     ,ValidTill     date
)

CREATE TABLE Brands
(
      ID            bigint NOT NULL
     ,Brand         varchar(100) 
)

CREATE TABLE Models
(
      ID            bigint NOT NULL
     ,BrandsID      bigint NOT NULL
     ,ModelName     varchar(100) 
)


CREATE TABLE ModelParts
(
      ModelsID      bigint NOT NULL 
     ,PartID        bigint NOT NULL
)
```

Fill your data like:

```
INSERT INTO Parts VALUES 
(1,'AA1007', 'Screw HyperFuturistic',   '2017-08-09', '9999-12-31'),
(1,'AA1001', 'Screw Iron',              '1800-01-01', '1918-06-30'),
(1,'AA1002', 'Screw Steel',             '1918-07-01', '1945-05-08'),
(1,'AA1004', 'Screw Titanium',          '1945-05-09', '1983-10-05'),
(1,'AA1005', 'Screw Futurium',          '1983-10-06', '2017-08-08')


INSERT INTO Brands VALUES 
(1,'Bosch'),
(2,'Indesit'),
(3,'Samsung'),
(4,'HotPoint'),
(5,'Sharp')


INSERT INTO Models VALUES 
(1,1,'A1'),
(2,1,'A2'),
(3,1,'A3'),
(4,2,'A1'),
(5,2,'A2')

INSERT INTO ModelParts VALUES 
(1,1)
```

To select all parts of a certain date (in this case 2013-03-03) of the "Bosch A1":

```
DECLARE @ReportingDate date = '2013-03-03'

         SELECT B.Brand
               ,M.ModelName
               ,P.PartNo
               ,P.PartName
               ,P.ValidFrom
               ,P.ValidTill
           FROM Brands B
     INNER JOIN Models M
             ON M.BrandsID  = B.ID
     INNER JOIN ModelParts MP
             ON MP.ModelsID = M.ID
     INNER JOIN Parts P
             ON P.ID = MP.PartID         
          WHERE B.Brand          = 'Bosch'
            AND M.ModelName      = 'A1'
            AND P.ValidFrom     <= @ReportingDate
            AND P.ValidTill     >= @ReportingDate
```

Of course there a several ways to do an historization of data. 
ValidFrom and ValidTill (ValidTo) is one of my favourites, as you can easily do historical reports.
Unfortunately you have to handle the historization: When inserting a new row - in example for your screw - you have to "close" the old record by setting the ValidTill column before inserting the new one. Furthermore you have to develop logic to handle deletes...

Well, thats a quite large topic. You will find tons of information in the world wide web.

Comment: Thank you. This was what I had in my mind. Thanks for clarifying things. However the part numbers are not clear for me. Please note that they are all same part (for example they are all the same screw), but in time the part number has changed. So I need to keep a track of these part numbers. The solution @Tim Biegeleisen has provided makes sense, but I couldn't figure out how to add a new previous part number. In this case, the previous part number I have added, would be the most recent one. Do you have an alternative solution to keep track of this?

Comment: @HappyForever i just updated my post. i removed the Partent/Child logic and added a timeband to the Parts table. this might be what you've been looking for

Comment: Yes this was what I was looking for. I was not sure if it is  a good practice to use so many tables with 2 fields, now I know it is a good practice. However, I am not sure how to update all connected fields when there are so many tables. I guess I will ask this as a different question.

Answer (score 2):

For the part number table, you can consider the following suggestion:

```
id | part_no | time_created
1  | AA1007  | 2017-08-08
1  | AA1001  | 2017-07-01
1  | AA1002  | 2017-06-10
1  | AA1004  | 2017-03-15
1  | AA1005  | 2017-01-30
```

In other words, you can add a `datetime` column which versions each part number.  Note that I added a primary key `id` column here, which is invariant over time and keeps track of each part, despite that the part number may change.

For time independent queries, you would join this table using the `id` column.  However, the part number might also serve as a foreign key.  Off the top of my head, if you were generating an invoice from a previous date, you might lookup the appropriate part number at that time, and then join out to one or more tables using that part number.

For the other tables you mentioned, I do not see a similar requirement.

Comment: 6 hours 6 minutes 5 seconds.  one second more and you're in for a hell'va time.  Viable answer.  I like it to manage part obsolescence and still have prior data; but if it's not an obsolescence activity, then we may need a child table with parent child hierarchy or synonyms but this works for some uses cases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a good solution for the previous part number table. However, timestamp is created automatically. So what if I want to adjust the previous part numbers, i.e. add another one, change the current one?

Comment: I didn't conceive of a previous part table, only one table which contains _all_ part numbers, current and previous.  You can always identify the current one, so you might not even need a separate table for previous ones.  Add and remove as you like (this comment might change if you have some other requirements in mind).

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen thank you for your comment. What would be the proper way to keep track of the previous part numbers? Sometimes there are no previous part number for a part, and sometimes there are 2, sometimes 9, so it varies. And whenever there is a replacement part (a new part), the current part number will be the previous one.

Comment: Well my idea, which may not work in practice, but might be a good start, is to just keep a single table with all parts and their timestamps.  This is what my answer tries to explain.  Add as many part numbers as you want, and tag them with timestamps to keep track of which one comes first.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Sorry for my ignorance, but I have hard time understanding the phrase "tag them with timestamps to keep track of which one comes first". As far as I know timestamps are automatically populated at the time of insert. So if I insert a previous part number, the timestamp of this partnumber will be latest one (it will act like the current part number, which is not). Please advise what you mean by "tag them with timestamps"?

Comment: @HappyForever You can choose whatever value you want for the timestamp, can you not?  I don't understand what you are confused over, to be honest.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This is what I mean: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592658/sql-server-updating-a-time-stamp-column. I cannot change the timestamp, whenever I insert or update, the timestamp updates automatically. Do you mean datetime instead of timestamp?

Comment: @HappyForever Please ignore my previous comments about timestamp.  I actually did not know that SQL Server timestamps cannot be updated.  So use `datetime` instead, which can be updated.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you for clarifying this. I was about to lose my mind keeping asking the same question and getting the same answer :) All sorted now.